# In listview all the values are getting inserted at firs position

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Below is my java class

the value of string s comes from database buffer,
I want that whenever the value comes i gets stored in listview as a first clickable  element ..
But what happens is all the values are getting stored at the first position of the listview as an item 1

```
             import android.database.Cursor;
             import android.os.Bundle;
              import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
              import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
              import android.widget.ListView;
              import android.widget.TextView;

              import java.util.ArrayList;
               import java.util.Arrays;


      public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ListView lv;
String s= null;
TextView tv1;
DatabaseHelper mydb;
StringBuffer buffer;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acticity_history);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Cursor res = mydb.getAllData();
    if(res.getCount() == 0)
    {
        return;

    }

    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(res.moveToNext()){
        buffer.append(""+ res.getString(1)+ "\n");
    }
    s = buffer.toString();

    String[] values = new String[]{s};


    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(values) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simpleraw, planetList);

    lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);} }
```

Below is my xml layout for listview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="true">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

below is my simpleraw layout file for textview

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your values are getting appended to the `String s`. Replace your code with the following,

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.acticity_history);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

Cursor res = mydb.getAllData();
if(res.getCount() == 0)
{
    return;
}

else
{
  ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
  while(res.moveToNext()){
    planetList.add(res.getString(1));
    }

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simpleraw, planetList);

   lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
  }
 } 
}
```

Set an OnItemClickListener to your listView,

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String itemName = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this,newActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("some_string", itemName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }               
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were appending string for database to a stringbuffer and 
The following code will not give you all items in array. The array will have only one item.

```
String[] values = new String[]{s};
```

Please use following code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acticity_history);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Cursor res = mydb.getAllData();
        if(res.getCount() == 0)
        {
            return;

        }

        ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(res.moveToNext()){
            planetList.add( res.getString(1));
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simpleraw, planetList);

   }
```